# zip and filter in python

Tags: python, filter, zip

Hi I am struggling with this can someone help?
"Write code using zip and filter so that these lists (l1 and l2) are combined into one big list and assigned to the variable opposites if they are both longer than 3 characters each."
data:

```
l1 = ['left', 'up', 'front']
l2 = ['right', 'down', 'back']
```

this is what I have:

```
l3=list(zip(l1,l2))
opposites=list(filter(lambda s:len(s)>3,l3))
```

The problem is that I need two arguments to be more than length 3.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can do it like this

```
l1 = ['left', 'up', 'front']
l2 = ['right', 'down', 'back']
l3 = zip(l1, l2)
opposites=list(filter(lambda s:len(s[0])>3 and len(s[1]) >3 ,l3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much , very helpfull

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create a third list, `l3 = zip(l1, l2)` of tuples outside the `filter()`. The `zip(l1, l2)` will provide the required sequence of tuples.

```
opposites = list(filter(lambda x: (len(x[0]) > 3 and len(x[1]) > 3), zip(l1, l2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this, using list comprehensions:

```
opposites = [(w1,w2) for (w1,w2) in list(zip(l1,l2)) if len(w1) > 3 and len(w2) > 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use this piece of code:

```py
opposites=filter(lambda tup : len(tuple[0])>3 and len(tuple[1])>3,zip(l1,l2))
```

Comment: The argument given to the `lambda` is `tup`, but then `tuple` is the name used in the lambda body; `tuple` should be changed to `tup` in both places for this to work.